# How to catch file size too large error in flask?

Tags: python, flask

In flask, there is an option for setting the maximum size of file uploaded as `app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1000 * 1000` but when it is placed for files above the limit it takes into a webpage showing RequestEntityTooLarge.

Is there a possibility that I can except this error and show my own error page to the user or a flash message instead? I tried to `except RequestEntityTooLarge:` but it is showing unknown error.

More on the exception is [here](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.RequestEntityTooLarge)

Comment: Flask 1.x documentation: [Custom Error Pages](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask 1.x documentation: [Custom Error Pages](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/)

You can use `@app.errorhandler(413)` to assign function which will be executed when file is too big - and this function may display custon template.

---

Minimal working code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 10

@app.errorhandler(413)
def page_not_found(e):
    #print(e)
    #print(dir(e))
    #return render_template(...)
    return 'File to big: ' + str(e)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file_image = request.files['image']
        print(dir(file_image.save))
        file_image.save(file_image.filename)
    return render_template_string('''
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<button type="submit" name="button" value="send">Send</button>
</form>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True 
    app.run()
```

---

I don't know if you could catch this error and run `flash()` - it may need much more work.

---

**EDIT:** Flask 2.x documentation: [Handling Application Errors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/errorhandling/)